# Is using "Key" design pattern in shader class possible?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, opengl, shader

First of all, i don't know if the "key" pattern is accepted as general patter, but some sorts of it have been appearing all over SO recently, so...

**What I want to do?**

Create shader manipulation class in C++. My issue here particularly focuses on setting uniform values (values sent from C++ to GLSL "directly").

**What's the problem?**

(Quick explanation, so that people not accustomed to OpenGL can contribute too) - 
Uniform variables are set by using global `glUniform*` functions, taking as first parameter the location of the uniform in currently bound shader (`int`);

So the common usage is:

```
glBindProgram(myProgramNum);
int Location = glGetUniformLocation(myProgramNum, "myUniformParameterName");
float myValue = 42.f; // arbitrary data
glUniform1f (Location, myValue);
```

I've created some of the methods I need to encapsulate the above, such as

```
void SetUniform1f (std::string const& name, float a);
void SetUniformVector3 (std::string const& name, CVector3 const& vec);
void SetUniformMatrix4 (std::string const& name, CMatrix4 const& mat);
```

I've noticed, however, that all these use the `glGetUniformLocation(int, const char*)`. As some of them will be used in realtime, this would cause unnecessary performance overhead.

**The first idea**

I've thought that I could create two versions of each function - one taking `std::string` and value, and second `int` and value, thus allowing faster access.

However, it would make them no better than the pure OpenGL access, since user would still be able to send malicious parameter to them.

**The second idea**

So, the proper way do to it would be to generate some sort of "Key" object from shader class, containing location of given uniform. It would however need to be linked to specific CShader class instance, because one could generate key in one object and pass it to another, causing unwanted behavior.

And my question is - is something like this possible in C++? Do I have to keep pointer to "parent" object in the key object and test if it's valid parameter every time, or are there any language/Boost features that will allow some sort of syntaxic sugar around it?

What I was able to deduce myself, the key class should be nested in CShader, and had CShader as friend. Also it should declare trivial constructor private, and overload copy-constructor so that copied objects will still be valid keys.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Having said that, no, there's no way to link two objects without keeping a pointer just like you described.

Comment: To defend myself, I can only say that I've seen a bar in gDEBugger called "Redundand Gets" and I was a bit concerned about it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only an integer to set an uniform variable. Indeed, instead of calling a bunch of `glGetUniformLocation`, why don't you cache those values in a `std::map<std::string, int>`? Querying the `map` would be faster, isn't it?

Not everything is clear in you question (parent pointer?, malicious values?), but at the end an hypothetical user of a `CShader` class wants a shortcut for setting up uniform values. Indeed you can query uniforms after shader linkage (using [glGetActiveUniform](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetActiveUniform.xml)) or you can query uniform and cache uniform location when necessary.

Comment: The use of `map` should be fast enough. I am not sure if I understood the last paragraph correctly, but do you intend to replace all of specialized setuniform calls by one overloaded one, which not only uses cached locations, but also cached uniform types? I really didn't think about the latter, it seems great though!

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Also I did not understand. Caching the type is nice debugging option, but I prefer to do that in debug compilations.